# «Ничто не интересует» или «ничего не интересует»?

Tags: грамматика

Казалось бы, правильно «ничто не интересует» (И.п.  местоименного сущ. в роли подлежащего), но в современной литературе в РАЗНЫХ СТИЛЯХ все чаще можно встретить форму «ничего не интересует», в то время как вариант «ничто» в большей степени характерен для текстов 19-20 веков. Интересно, что форму «ничто не болит» Нацкорпус вообще не находит.

Как  это можно объяснить?

ПРИМЕРЫ

Вот этот излишек я и люблю, а больше меня ничего не интересует (Д. Быков). Ко всему привыкли ― к любви, к искусству, к революции. Ничего не интересует. Вас больше ничего не интересует, Георгий Николаевич? (В. П. Катаев) Он уделил несколько минут будущей теще, притворяясь, что ничего не интересует его, кроме невесты (А. С. Грин).

А меня ничто не интересует, ― сказал Румата (Стругацкие). По правде вам сказать, меня теперь ничто не интересует (А. Я. Панаева). Отвыкла. Ничто не интересует. Говорю вам, совсем одичала (М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин).

КОММЕНТАРИЙ К ОТВЕТУ

1) ЧТО ПОКАЗАЛОСЬ ИНТЕРЕСНЫМ

1. Форма НИЧТО стилистически воспринимается как книжная, устаревающая. А форма НИЧЕГО рассматривается как нейтральная
2. Предложениях форма «ничего» бесспорно выступает в роли подлежащего, пусть даже его грамматического эквивалента.
3. Здесь, возможно, возвратность сбивает на безличное, но по структуре предложение то же, что и предыдущие – двусоставное.

2) КАКИЕ ВЫВОДЫ МОЖНО СДЕЛАТЬ

1. Сравним варианты: Что-то звенит. || Ничего не звенит. Что-то происходит. || Ничего не происходит. Что-то жужжит. || Ничего там не жужжит.
   Они отличаются активностью производителей действия, мыслимых как одушевленный или неодушевленный предмет. При этом пассивность и неопределенность подлежащего что-то/ничего  сближает эти грамматически двусоставные предложения с безличными, что особенно заметно при отрицании.
2. Что тебя интересует. – Ничего не интересует.  Что тебе интересно? – Ничего не интересно. Что у тебя болит? – Ничего не болит. Наличие субъекта отрицается, и предложение по семантике сближается с безличным, не имеющим производителя вообще.
3. Фактически грамматическое ПОДЛЕЖАЩЕЕ  «ничего» и по грамматике (Р.п.), и по смыслу воспринимается как ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
4. Именно поэтому форма «ничего» перестает быть разговорной и превращается по факту в нейтральную.

Comment: "Ничто не должно отвлекать" - пример предпочтительности местоимения "ничто"))!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сейчас форма НИЧТО стилистически воспринимается как книжная, устаревающая. А форма НИЧЕГО рассматривается как нейтральная.

Выражение подлежащего не только формой Им. п., но и формой Род. п. носит название «грамматических эквивалентов именительного падежа подлежащего» (Е. Попов).

Е. Попов считает, что «предложения с “правильным” именительным падежом отрицательного местоимения воспринимаются порой как книжные, имеющие несколько искусственный характер» (Попов Е. Грамматические эквиваленты именительного падежа подлежащего // РЯШ. 1971. № 4)

О конструкциях с родительным падежом, сближающихся по своей синтаксической роли с подлежащим, говорит и Ю. М. Костинский.

Сближающихся, но не являющихся подлежащими.
Валгина, к примеру, пишет (об инфинитивных предложениях):

Такие предложения обычно распространяются дополнением со значением объекта и свойственны разговорной речи. Ср.: Ничего не слышно. - Ничего не слыхать. Примеры: Лукашка сидел один, смотрел на отмель и прислушивался, не слыхать ли казаков (Л. Т.); Я поглядывал в небо - не видать ли перелетных птиц.

Что он говорит? - Ничего (он) не говорит. (Дополнение.)

Они ничего не принесли. (Дополнение.)

Но есть другие структуры, весьма многочисленные.

Что-то жужжит. - Ничего там не жужжит.

Что-то пролетело. - Да ничего не пролетело. Спи.

Что-то происходит. - Ничего особенного не происходит. (Подлежащее здесь «ничего особенного».)

В последних трех предложениях форма «ничего» бесспорно выступает в роли подлежащего, пусть даже его грамматического эквивалента.

Кто-то поет.|| Никто не поет.

Что-то звенит. || Ничего не звенит.

Что-то происходит. || Ничего не происходит.

Что-то ужасное произошло. || Ничего ужасного не произошло. (Подлежащие соответственно «что-то ужасное» и «ничего ужасного».)

Что-то случилось. || Ничего не случилось. (Здесь, возможно, возвратность сбивает на безличное, но по структуре предложение то же, что и предыдущие - двусоставное.)

Comment: Спасибо. Подобная точка зрения мне близка и понятна, подробнее я отвечу в дополнении к ответу.

Comment: Среди заданий на ГИА в 9 классе есть задание выписать грамматическую основу. Так в прошлом году на экзамене было такое предложение. Тесты были заранее выложены в Интернет, но как было угадать, что разработчики КИМов считают верным? Кстати, правильным был засчитан ответ, в котором подлежащее указано не было.

Comment: А какое именно предложение? Меня ничего не интересует? Или просто похожее? Нужно разбираться в каждом случае.Такого примера на ГИА не должно быть, как и генитивных - это не уровень школы, в школе, если встретятся, разбираются как односоставные безличные. Я что-то такого предложения не помню, хотя к ГИА готовила.

Comment: "Ничего, к сожалению, не вышло..."

Comment: Да, этот пример  тоже некорректный, но воспринимается всё-таки как безличное, если не начинать копаться. Что из этого вышло?-ничего не вышло. Не вышло=ничего нет, а "нет" всегда обезличенно. Дети обычно рассуждают так:нет сущ. в им пад., значит, нет подлежащего, а начинаешь копаться - появляются сомнения, мудрствования на уровне высшей школы, им этого просто не понять. Я думаю, правильно, что в школе нет этих заумностей.

Answer (score 4):

Я, конечно, не настолько специалист, чтобы давать квалифицированный комментарий, но, мне кажется, что форма "ничего не интересует" все-таки разговорная. Потому что по всем канонам русского языка не интересовать должно все-таки "ничто", которое тут выступает в роли подлежащего. А "ничего"... Ничего, оно и есть ничего)))

Comment: Форма, конечно, разговорная, но претендует на основную. Интересно, что до 1900 года вариант "ничего" вообще не использовался, а активно применяться  стал где-то после 1980 года,  причем не только для речевой характеристики героев, но  и в текстах различного стиля. И есть что-то архаичное  в этом "ничто".

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "у вас ничего не болит" режет слух. На вопрос "что у вас болит?" должен последовать ответ "ничто не болит", но ни в коем случае не "у меня ничего не болит".