# Ничего/ничто не беспокоит

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, местоимения

Моя немолодая знакомая сказала, что ей режет слух, когда говорят *"**ничто** не беспокоит".*

На сайте уже был [подобный вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37548/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82).

Я ей сказал, что мне всё видится следующим образом. Когда это ответ на вопрос, допустимо только "ничего", "ничто" не годится, например:

*— Что тебя беспокоит?

— (А) **ничего** не беспокоит.*

В случаях, когда есть слово "больше" перед "ничего", как в примерах по ссылке, тогда предпочтительно именно это слово *(ничего).* Повторю эти примеры:

> *Вот этот излишек я и люблю, а **больше** меня **ничего** не интересует (Д. Быков).
>
>   Вас **больше ничего** не интересует, Георгий Николаевич? (В. П. Катаев)*

Дальше я сказал, что когда есть отдельное утверждение, не ответ и не противопоставление, тогда предпочтительно *"ничто",* например:

> *В это прекрасное майское утро Ивана Тимофеича **ничто** не беспокоило.*

Правильно я рассудил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Артем, я посмотрела ответы наших участников в 2014 году и сравнила с вашим ответом. Могу сказать, что ваше мнение намного интереснее,  чувство языка у вас есть несомненное.

Я дам **свой ответ**, и хотя он отличается от вашего, но **сходные признаки есть**.

Я просмотрела **примеры из Нацкорпуса** и сделала такие выводы.

1) На выбор формы ***ничто не*** и ***ничего не*** влияет как смысл, так и стиль.
 Форма ***ничего не*** встречается значительно чаще, но и для  ***ничто не*** находится около 6 тысяч примеров. Так что не очень-то она устарела.

2) Часто эти формы **взаимозаменяемы**, но иногда форма ***ничто не*** мне кажется более  предпочтительной. Вот эти примеры:

Ныне, после того как взошло яркое солнце чудесного зрелища, ***ничто*** не может остановить меня.

У него есть важное достоинство: с любого кресла хорошо видно, потому что ***ничто*** не закрывает сцены.

***Ничто*** так не ожесточает человека, ***как*** потерянная надежда.

В таком городишке ***ничто*** не остаётся секретом...

Сериал. ***Ничто*** не случается дважды.

**Теперь нужна гипотеза.** Я предполагаю, что форма Р.п. здесь обозначает **полноту отрицания,** то есть действуют обычное правило для Р.п.

При использовании И.п. мы как бы представляем ряд конкретных предметов и отрицаем эти предметы, но **о полноте отрицания речи нет.** В эту картинку вписывается ваш пример со словом *больше*, там полнота отрицания явно просматривается. А в приведенных предложениях из Нацкорпуса или отрицается конкретный ряд, или  делается выбор из этого ряда.

А теперь обратимся **к классикам**.

Унынья моего ***ничто*** не мучит, не тревожит.

***Ничто*** на Земле не проходит бесследно, И юность ушедшая все же бессмертна.

Замена родительным падежом возможна, но  **менее художественна**. Вот о чем говорится  у Пушкина? Не тревожит ничто из того, что тревожило раньше, а это вполне **конкретные события, переживания.**

Вот такое решение я могу предложить, но  это тоже частное мнение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень интересно, особенно про полноту отрицания!

Comment: Перечитал сейчас, и мне кажется, что там, где вы упоминаете в. п., должен быть именительный.

Comment: Да, Артем, вы правы,  это я по аналогии вспомнила о правилах различения Р.п. и В.п. существительных при глаголах с отрицанием.