# Сложная синтаксическая конструкция (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сравнительный-оборот, и

Скажите, пожалуйста, ставилась бы запятая перед ***и***, если бы не было сравнительного оборота?

Маяковский ходил среди людей, как Гулливер, и хотя нисколько не заботился о том, чтобы они ощущали себя рядом с ним лилипутами, но как-то само собой выходило, что самым заносчивым людям не удавалось взглянуть на него свысока.

[...] (?) и [хотя...Гл.+ук.М.], но [...], что [...]

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, конкретный пример. В той схеме, которой вы приводите, нет однородных членов. [...] (?) и [хотя...],следовательно, не образует однородную пару. Если, конечно, вы это это место имели в виду.

Comment: @Alena 1. Цитировать необходимо дословно: **...будет огорчена...**  (https://klassika.ru/read.html?proza/dostoevskij/unizh.txt&page=30) 2. В этом предложении нет ни "и", ни "хотя". 3. Думаю, Вам надо переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Схема явно не относится  к этому предложению. В приведённом предложении знаки препинания верны, кроме ошибочной запятой после "наверно", потому что это не вводное слово, а устаревающее наречие в значении "несомненно, точно" (она несомненно будет огорчена)

Comment: Я перепутала предложение. Исправила.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Схема предложения, по моему скромному мнению, должна выглядеть так:

[...], и (хотя...), (чтобы...), но [...], (что...)

Запятая перед ***и*** будет ставиться в любом случае, независимо от того, закрывается ли сравнительный оборот перед ним, или он отсутствует.

Здесь наблюдается [встреча сочинительного и подчинительного союзов](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188). Союз ***и*** соединяет первое простое главное предложение со всем последующим сложноподчиненным предложением, где главное (***как-то само собой выходило***) имеет три придаточных разного порядка.

Второе предложение с уступительным союзом ***хотя*** является придаточным второго порядка, оно подчиняется последнему предложению, его можно перенести в самый конец (после ***свысока***) вместе с его же придаточным (с союзом ***чтобы***). Тогда бы союз ***и*** исчез, и оба главных предложения были соединены сочинительным союзом ***но***. К тому же в этом втором предложении подразумевается подлежащее ***он***. Такой [вариант предложения](https://znanija.com/task/14855016) есть на просторах интернета.

Ещё, как мне представляется, запятая перед ***как Гулливер*** не нужна, поскольку Маяковский не просто *ходил* среди людей, а *ходил Гулливером*. Без этого оборота (выражающего образ действия) предложение не имеет необходимого смысла; оборот тесно связан со сказуемым и не должен отделяться от него. На эту мысль меня навёл
[вариант предложения с *ходил Гулливером*](https://yandex.ru/tutor/subject/problem/?problem_id=T11279).

Comment: Правильное предложение немного другое, и "как Гулливер" без запятых (поддерживаю, здесь Вы правы). К .Чуковский писал так: _Но он ходил среди людей как Гулливер, и хотя нисколько не старался о том, чтобы они ощущали себя рядом с ним лилипутами, но как-то так само собою делалось, что самым спесивым и заносчивым людям не удавалось взглянуть на него свысока._ http://www.poslushayte.ru/vospominaniya_sovremennikov.php

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, Римма!

Comment: Нет, не получала (сейчас гляну). Вы знаете, иногда такое бывает на сайте — что сообщения не доходят. Пару раз я обращала на это внимание модераторов.

Answer (score 4):

Всем привет и поздравления с праздником! Иногда заглядываю посмотреть, как тут у вас дела.

Запятая перед И ставится  и при отсутствии оборота, так как далее следует СПП с тремя придаточными:

*Не то чтобы он был надменен. Но он ходил среди людей как Гулливер, и хотя нисколько не старался о том, чтобы они ощущали себя рядом с ним лилипутами, но как-то само собою делалось, что самым спесивым и заносчивым не удавалось взглянуть на него свысока* (К.И.Чуковский).

1) Грамматический разбор, данный в ответе, **не совсем верен в части характеристики придаточных.** Придаточное с союзом ХОТЯ – это придаточное первого порядка, вторая часть союза НО относится к главному предложению. Придаточное с союзом ЧТО – первый порядок, придаточное с союзом ЧТОБЫ – второй порядок. 
Это выглядит примерно так:

**Но он ходил среди людей как Гулливер, и хотя нисколько не старался о том**, (чтобы…), **но как-то само собою делалось**, (что…)

2) Примечание

**Здесь вот что еще интересно.** Запятая перед И  будет ставиться и в таком предложении: *Но он **ходил** среди людей как Гулливер, и хотя нисколько не **стремился** к этому, но всегда **казался** выше других.*

Здесь присутствуют только однородные  сказуемые, поэтому кажется, что перед И запятая не нужна. Но дело в том, что при наличии двойного союза ХОТЯ…НО сказуемые 2 и 3 образуют СПП, перед которым  ставится запятая.

Об этом ясно сказано у Розенталя п. 4 
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140 Сравнить:  *Он носил тёмные очки, фуфайку, уши закладывал ватой, и когда садился на извозчика, то приказывал поднимать верх.*

3) **О запятой  перед сравнительным оборотом**

Маяковский ходил среди людей  () как Гулливер…

В текстах встречаются оба варианта, и это вполне возможно, так как однозначного решения нет.  При обособлении оборота меняется **расстановка логических ударений** (объяснение «ходил Гулливером» представляется мне несколько формальным). В то же время необособленный вариант **с одним ударением** кажется более логичным, а к тому же это вроде бы **авторская** версия.

Сравнить:

Но он ходил среди людЕй, как ГулливЕр… (1)

Но он ходил среди людей как ГулливЕр… (2)

Comment: Sharon, здавствуйте, с праздником!  1. Исправьте: _запятая перед И **не** будет ставиться_. 2.  По поводу порядка придаточного ввели меня в размышления, сомнения. Почему Вы считаете, что предлодение с _хотя_ относится к первому главному? По-моему, всё логично: _людям не удавалось, хотя (несмотря на то что, даже когда) он не заботился_. Если бы не было союза _хотя_, то да.  3.  Если делать акцент на _людЕй_, то _как Гулливер_ будет присоединением?  Всё-таки без запятой лучше.

Comment: О! И я присоединяюсь — с праздником!

Comment: @ Александр Стрелец  Спасибо за правку.  Что касается грамматического разбора, то грамматика данного предложения мне представляется вполне ясной. Рассмотрим отдельно СПП:  ХОТЯ (ОН) НИСКОЛЬКО НЕ СТАРАЛСЯ О ТОМ, НО КАК-ТО САМО СОБОЮ ЭТО ДЕЛАЛОСЬ. Вроде бы корректное предложение с придаточным уступительным, всё на месте? Двухместный союз ХОТЯ…НО, в придаточной части сообщается о ситуации, которая противоречит ситуации в главной части.  Это основная структура, а остальные придаточные являются распространителями

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Спасибо, очень приятно видеть вас на сайте.

Comment: Да, я много думал над этим, крутил и так и так. Мне, наверно, не надо было упоминать о порядках, а просто написать "придаточное". Как считаете, лучше изменить ответ?  И не по теме: я получил этот комментарий только потому, что поставил отметку "отслеживать ответ". Чтобы комментарий дошёл наверняка, пишите, пожалуйста, имя и знак без пробелов: @АлександрСтрелец.

Comment: Не думаю, что надо менять ответ, ведь вопрос был о запятой, а не о грамматике. Альтернативные ответы  мне кажутся более интересными, чем однозначные. Они вызывают у людей желание думать и иметь собственное мнение.

Comment: Да, я тоже так думаю. И после своего комментария снова смотрю на предложение и колеблюсь...

Comment: Вот и прекрасно, желаю вам найти для себя верный вариант.  Я тоже сомневалась после вашего комментария и даже спросила у своего любимого  справочника: “Свет мой, книжечка, скажи, да всю правду доложи". Просмотрела грамматический материал, но всё-таки посчитала свое решение верным.

Comment: @Sharon: с возвращением вас! А я уж боялся, что вы навсегда пропали!

Comment: Артемчик, привет!  Как-то вот не получается навсегда пропасть. Да вы тоже не часто заглядываете, а у меня не так много друзей. Так что приходите, задавайте свои интересные вопросы.

Comment: У меня было такое, что я где-то 230 или больше дней подряд заходил, часто ничем не отмечался, но хотя бы заглядывал. А вопросам уж не прикажешь, рождаются не по заказу. :)

Comment: Кстати, на мой [последний вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460199/%d0%9d%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82) так никто и не ответил, только кто-то проголосовал за него.

Comment: Артем, ваши вопросы мне нравятся тем, что они взяты из окружающей нас жизни, в то время как большинство вопросов на форуме связаны с учебной или практической деятельностью. Я вот люблю слушать, как говорят незнакомые люди, какие обороты речи они употребляют. Такой материал очень ценный, тем  ваши вопросы и хороши. Это как бы портрет поколения, будут вас потом историки цитировать. А неотвеченный вопрос я посмотрела, но там надо подумать, так что отвечу чуть позже, по возможности.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Арин! Приятно это слышать. И я с этим полностью согласен.)) Спасибо заранее!