# "Ничто" или "ничего" в конкретном примере?

Tags: морфология

*Он ничего (ничто) не пустит по ветру: ни денег (ни деньги), ни имущества (ни имущество).*

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37548/Ничто-не-интересует-или-ничего-не-интересует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Он ничего не пустит по ветру: ни деньги, ни имущество.***

Пояснение:

1) Про выбор ***ничего*** уже сказано в ответах по ссылке [«Ничто не интересует» или «ничего не интересует»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37548/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82)

2) Далее выбираю **винительный падеж** для существительных, расположенных на расстоянии от глагола с частицей НЕ.

**Пишу по слуху, как Пушкин,** и руководствуюсь его замечанием: "Неужто электрическая сила отрицательной частицы должна пройти сквозь всю эту цепь глаголов и отозваться в существительном?"

Сравнить: *Нет ничего: ни денег, не имущества.*

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67